# Find largest value rows based on one group in column and pivot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
id  val city    
4   78  a   
4   12  b   
4   50  c   

9   20  d   
9   8   e   
9   30  f   
9   17  g
```

I want to convert it into the following shape. Within each 'id' group, get the nlargest rows (n=2 in this case) based on 'val'. e.g. 78 & 50 in group with id 4 and 30 & 20 in group with id 9

```
id  val city    
4   78  a   
4   50  c   

9   30  f   
9   20  d
```

Finally, pivot the table as follows:

```
id  c_1stLrgst  c_1Lrgst_val    c_2ndLrgst  c_2Lrgst_val...c_nLrgst c_nLrgst_val
4   a           78              c           50
9   f           30              d           20
```

I'm able to get the groups by using `df.groupby('id').nlargest(2, 'val')`. Not sure what to do next.

```
import pandas as pd
df_dict = {'id': [4,4,4,9,9,9,9],
            'val':[78,12,50,20,8,30,17],    
            'city':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 
            };
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort_values` + `groupby.head`, followed by another `groupby` to `list`. Then split the lists and concatenate.

```
# sort by "val" descending and extract first 2 rows from each group
df_filtered = df.sort_values('val', ascending=False)\
                .groupby('id').head(2)

groupvars = ['city', 'val']

# groupby city and val
g = df_filtered.groupby('id')[groupvars].agg(list)

# split lists and create dataframe for each group key
L = [pd.DataFrame(g[x].values.tolist(), index=res.index).add_prefix(x) for x in groupvars]

# concatenate results
res = pd.concat(L, axis=1)

print(res)

   city0 city1  val0  val1
id                        
4      a     c    78    50
9      f     d    30    20
```

Comment: The first part works very well!. However I need to better explain the pivot. I don't need to preserve the countries. Edited the question. I only need 2 columns which would contain the top n values, hence a one column for the city name and one column for city value

Comment: If I use city as columns, it would mean that I would get as many columns as there are cities, instead of getting city 1 and city 2

Comment: @orak, Please see update, hopefully this is closer to what you're looking for.